# How to count argc in C

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, argv, argc

I am having problem with, getting right number of parameters:

```
    while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, ":a:c:SL")) != -1)
```

If i start script: 
`./script -a ok -c 1 -S -L` 
 argc variable equals to 7

**Problem**  is when i want to start script as `./script -a ok -c 1 -SS -L`  argc variable equals 7, but it should be 8 cause (SS (or LL/CC) would needs to be count as two).

Comment: `arc`? `argc`! And no, `argc` is the number of space-delimited arguments, it has nothing to do with how `getopt` parses them.

Comment: Why do you care about the value if `argc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I suspect that the reason you want to count the number of arguments that `getopt` processes is to access any following arguments that are not options.

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) points to the solution:

> If there are no more option characters, `getopt()` returns -1. Then
>   `optind` is the index in `argv` of the first `argv`-element that is not an
>   option.

Once your `while` loop completes, you can do the following:

```
int i;
for (i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("non-option arument: %s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Alternately, you can move up `argv` so that it points to the the first non-option argument, and decrement `argc` accordingly.  Then you can start indexing from 0:

```
argc -= optind;
argv += optind;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("non-option arument: %s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can't do that. If that's the case then you need to parse the argument yourself and understand it yourself. Most of the standard commands work this way.</strike>

You can't change what argc counts and how it counts. To get the proper number of counts without the `getopt` you can simply count your `argv` on your own.

In my small programs if I need this kind of things I just check each of the arguments (without `getopt`).

With `getopt` you can correctly get all the options. You can get `-SSS` and then you can decide what is the behavior as per that option.

Instead of writing your own <strike>parser</strike> option counting or processing logic or something similar, there is a nice and cleaner way to achieve the same thing.(**xtofl**'s comment).

> The simple idea is to use the multicharacter options to be `-S 3`
>   which would mean that `-SSS`. This way you can always parse it easily
>   and also get the idea also about what kind of behavior user expects
>   from the program specified through the options.<sup>1</sup>

#### A small example:

```
static const char help[] =
    "  -h       help help all this\n"
    "  -m times multiply by times\n"
    "  -s size  shift by size\n"
    "  -a add   addition by add\n"
    ;

int opt;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hm:s:a:")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'h':
        puts(help);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    case 'm':
        opm = atoi(optarg);
        break;
    case 's':
        ops = atoi(optarg);
        break;
    case 'a':
        opa = atoi(optarg);
        break;
    default:
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

<sup>1. It's a matter of opinion which one is used. Both are equally usable in different utilities. The underlying way of interpreting the thing changes a little. Apart from that they are mostly same.</sup>

Comment: Maybe `getopt` doesn't allow that because it's not a good idea.  Maybe use an optional 'count' argument `S::C::` to be used like `program -S -C 3`

Comment: @xtofl.: I am sorry for a late reply. I have a really tired day. This is not an excuse (I shouldn';t have answered if I can't give time). Can you please elaborate on what you meant in the comment? I will work on my DV and the content itself. Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: Actually, this is more like a corollary of your answer: instead of trying to 'abuse' getopt, or worse, roll out your own option parser, OP could find a more compatible way to define the parameters: instead of counting the number of S'es, he could add a multiplier-argument (i.s.o. `-sss`, use `-s 3`).

Comment: ah I see... @xtofl Yes that's pretty cool. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @xtofl.: Check the answer once...and let me know if it looks ok. And yes thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks great.  Wooh and I'm mentioned in bold face!  You could add some example code as to how to interpret the absence of the -S as 0, plain -S as 1 and -S x as x.  Default options etc... you know?

Comment: @xtofl.: I can try that. But all this would work above `getopt` so yes I will try.

Comment: @xtofl.: Can you check this once more?

Comment: @rici.: Sorry? where do you find that "that"?

Comment: @rici.: My answer says that you can't change `argc` to return a count that is not `the number of space delimited options`...I didnt even mention `getops`. ALl this was about count part.

Comment: @rici.: I have given the code myself..which supports the feauture `getopt` holds. Maybe I should clarify my ansewer a bit?

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit, then. I certainly didn't understand "that" to mean "change argc". (Of course, you can change `argc`; it's not at all uncommon to see `argv += optind; argc -= optind;` or such-like.) But `getopt` will certainly handle `-SS` correctly (by recognizing it as two separate options).

Comment: Better, certainly. The claim that `-S3` is somehow "better" than `-SSS` is pure opinion; utilities which are "verbose" with `-v` and "more verbose" with `-vv` exist, for example. The point is that getopt works with both styles. In one case, the action is `verbosity = atoi(optarg)`; is n the other it is `++verbosity;`.

Comment: @rici.: Hey...yes. I just showed the alternative way. Didn't mean better but a lot cleaner. I will note yours as note.

Answer (score 0):

`getopt` will interpret `-SS` as two `S` options. Similarly, it will interpret `-SL` as an `S` option folliwed by an `L` option. It will also interpret both `-c2` and `-c 2` as a `c` option with argument `2`,  even though the first one is a single command line argument and the second one is two arguments.

`argc` tells you how many command lime arguments were passed, but it cannot tell you how many options will be parsed. That shouldn't be a problem, though.